# Several targets with distinct dependencies that use the same rule

Tags: makefile

My Makefile looks like this:

```
MODULES = core models pages admin
CMXSFILES = $(patsubst %,%.cmxs,$(MODULES))

all : $(CMXSFILES)

core.cmxs : core
  make -C $< ../$@

models.cmxs : models core.cmxs
  make -C $< ../$@

pages.cmxs : pages core.cmxs models.cmxs
  make -C $< ../$@

admin.cmxs : admin core.cmxs models.cmxs
  make -C $< ../$@
```

Is there a way to express the four last rules in a more concise way, given that the build command is exactly the same?

Something like this:

```
core.cmxs: core
models.cmxs: models core.cmxs
pages.cmxs: pages core.cmxs models.cmxs
admin.cmxs: admin core.cmxs models.cmxs
  make -C $< ../$@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you should never use `make` when invoking recursive makes.  Always use `$(MAKE)` (or `${MAKE}` if you prefer, same thing).

You can do this:

```
all: $(CMXFILES)

$(CMXFILES):
        $(MAKE) -C $< ../$@

core.cmxs: core
models.cmxs: models core.cmxs
pages.cmxs: pages core.cmxs models.cmxs
admin.cmxs: admin core.cmxs models.cmxs
```

But there are problems here.  First you need to declare all these directories as `.PHONY` otherwise they may not get built when you expect.  Also if you're using GNU make (which you likely are here since many make versions don't set `$<` on explicit rules) then you can use pattern rules to make things simpler:

```
all: $(CMXFILES)
.PHONY: $(CMXFILES:%.cmxs=%)

%.cmxs: %
        $(MAKE) -C $< ../$@

models.cmxs: core.cmxs
pages.cmxs: core.cmxs models.cmxs
admin.cmxs: core.cmxs models.cmxs
```

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't know we could specify dependencies and rules separately. Besides I'm not sure about putting the directories as PHONY, I put directories as dependencies so that make recompiles modules whence at least one file in it changed. I'll give it a shot anyway. And thanks for the $(MAKE) trick! :-)

Comment: Directory timestamps don't change when files in them change: that's a common misconception.  Directory timestamps change when the _directory's_ contents change: whenever a file is added, deleted, or renamed in that directory... but not when an existing file is updated.  It's possible that whatever process you use to update files in that directory always causes the directory to change as a side-effect: your editor creates temporary files or something.  But if you just use `echo hi >> foo` to an existing file `foo` then the directory's modification time will not change.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. As you surely have guessed by now, I'm not used to Makefiles :D Is it good practice to force make to recursively go through directories using `$(MAKE) -B -C $< ../$@`? The number of subdirectories is relatively small and I don't care about such a small time loss if it can spare me a `make clean && make all` every time I change a file somewhere...

Comment: I would definitely not use `-B`... if you do then you  might as well forget makefiles and just write a shell script to do your build, as everything will be built every time anyway.  I'm not sure why you suggested it so I can't address that issue.

Comment: You are right, `-B` is not what I want, I just want to execute the subsequent make unconditionally, but now I realize that this is exactly what .PHONY is meant for. You gave me the solution right away and I could not see it ... Sorry about the fuss, and thanks again !